# Map function gives unresolved function or method(map)

Tags: angular, typescript

Map method returns "Unresolved function or method map()" error even after I added `'rxjs/add/operator/map'` import.

I followed every step, I even added rxjs 5.0.1, I still come across with "Unresolved function or method" error. Do you know a way how to fix it?

You can see the sample code below.

Method that returns "Unresolved function or method error at map":

```
 import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
 import { Router } from '@angular/router';
 import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
 import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers, Response  } from '@angular/http';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
 import 'rxjs/Rx';

 @Component({
 moduleId: module.id,
 templateUrl: 'navigation.component.html'

 })

 export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {

 form: FormGroup;

 myInput = {input1:'',input2:'' }

 webserviceUrl : "https://httpbin.org/get";

 ngOnInit(): void { }

 constructor(private router: Router) {

}

constructor (private http: Http) {}


onRegister() {
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.post(this.webserviceUrl, options)
  .map(this.myInput)
  .catch(this.handleError);


 }

 private handleError (error: Response | any) {

let errMsg: string;
if (error instanceof Response) {
  const body = error.json() || '';
  const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
  errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
} else {
  errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
}
console.error(errMsg);
return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe map takes a function as it's parameter, but you are passing an object.  This error could be typescript not being able to find a map function that accepts and object.

Comment: unfortunately I tried everything to fix this issue. Even I give null parameters, string parameters but it still gives same error. I believe it'snot related with to find a map that accepts and object

Answer (score 0):

`Map` uses a function to modify the data.

In your http post, I'm suspecting you are wanting to get the return values from the http call and give the values to your variable `this.myInput`.  Instead of doing this:

```
return this.http.post(this.webserviceUrl, options)
  .map(this.myInput)
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

You probably want to return the json and then in your `subscribe` function to `onRegister()` assign the values to `this.myInput`.  It would look like this:

```
onRegister() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.webserviceUrl, options)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And then subscribe to it like this:

```
this.onRegister().subscribe(data => this.myInput = data);
```

Comment: Yes Tyler it is what I want. But still "map" says unresolved function or method

Comment: It sounds like maybe your npm install is corrupt.  I would delete your `node_modules` folder, run `npm cache clean`, then an `npm install` again to refresh all your dependencies.  The `import 'rxjs/Rx';` in redundant in your code.  You only need the `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`.